# Emitted events do not appear in historian of Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have a network developed in Hyperledger Composer. When I deployed it and start the Hyperledger Composer Playground via connection hlfv1 (with an environment of Hyperledger Fabric), when I submit a transaction, the events emmited by that transaction do not appear.

Versions:

Hyperledger Composer playground - v0.19.7

Hyperledger Composer - v0.19.7

Node.js - v8.11.2

npm - 6.1.0

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: this will likely be fixed in the next Composer release (0.19.9) - ie via PR https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/pull/4123 - this issue has already been captured here -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/4113

Comment: ps ordinarily, as an aside, Composer currently (June 2018) officially supports npm v 5.x fyi -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs